# Can I put a DDR3 ram in DDR3L slot

Tags: ddr3

So I have a [mini-PC](https://www.zotac.com/au/product/mini_pcs/ei730) which I need to buy RAM for.

Now the specs say that it supports DDR3-***L***.

I am thinking of getting the following kit:

```
CORSAIR Vengeance (2x8) 16GB 204-Pin SO-DIMM
Model CMSX16GX3M2B1600C9
DDR3 1600 (PC3 12800)
Cas Latency 9
1.35V (also supports operation at 1.5V)
Dual Channel Kit
Timing: 9-9-9-24
```

My question is whether this will work for a slot that is specified as DDR3 **L**?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR3L#DDR3L_and_DDR3U) says the major difference is that DDR3L is 1.35V, and the memory is stated to work at 1.35V, so I'd imagine so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Dell's article](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN153768/EN), **you won't be able to put DDR3 into DDR3L slot and get it to work** because boards utilizing DDR3L expect your memory to work on 1.35V, compared to 1.5 v that DDR3 memory requires.

However, it would work the other way around: DDR3L is designed to support both 1.35V and 1.5V operating voltages. As a general advice, you should also look up your board's memory support list.  Who knows what kind of voodoo magic manufacturer used on your board; you might even be able to get it to work :)

EDIT: In your case, **that memory stick would work fine**, because it is a DDR3L stick. The difference between DDR3 and DDR3L is only in operating voltage; DDR3 operates only at 1.5V, while DDR3L operates on both 1.5V and 1.35V, as stated above. Other than that, they are pretty much the same (at least from practical standpoint).

Comment: the physical slots are identical. From his question that ram would probably work too. Its all about the voltage after all.

Comment: @Hennes If you read everything carefully, it looks like the RAM would not be getting under-volted.  The provided specifications of this particular RAM stick said it supported 1.35V.

Comment: Ah. Drat. Good point. I completely missed the `(also supports operation at 1.5V)`